Error "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: CreationExtras must have a value by `SAVED_STATE_REGISTRY_OWNER_KEY'" when migrating to Jetpack
Following the Now In Android example app I am migrating my code to Jetpack Compose.
When opening the application, it ends with the following fatal error:
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: CreationExtras must have a value by `SAVED_STATE_REGISTRY_OWNER_KEY`
     at androidx.lifecycle.SavedStateHandleSupport.createSavedStateHandle(SavedStateHandleSupport.kt:89)
     at dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.HiltViewModelFactory$2.create(HiltViewModelFactory.java:100)
     at dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.HiltViewModelFactory.create(HiltViewModelFactory.java:170)
     at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$Factory.create(ViewModelProvider.android.kt:158)
     at androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.ViewModelProviderImpl.getViewModel$lifecycle_viewmodel_release(ViewModelProviderImpl.kt:69)
     at androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.ViewModelProviderImpl.getViewModel$lifecycle_viewmodel_release$default(ViewModelProviderImpl.kt:47)
     at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.android.kt:91)
     at androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.compose.ViewModelKt__ViewModelKt.get(ViewModel.kt:162)
     at androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.compose.ViewModelKt.get(Unknown Source:1)
     at androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.compose.ViewModelKt__ViewModel_androidKt.viewModel(ViewModel.android.kt:124)
     at androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.compose.ViewModelKt.viewModel(Unknown Source:1)
     at my.package.app.feature.foryou.ForYouScreenKt.ForYouRoute(ForYouScreen.kt:617)
     at my.package.app.feature.foryou.navigation.ForYouNavigationKt$forYouScreen$3.invoke(ForYouNavigation.kt:30)
     at my.package.app.feature.foryou.navigation.ForYouNavigationKt$forYouScreen$3.invoke(ForYouNavigation.kt:29)
     at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:139)
     at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:35)
     at androidx.navigation.compose.NavHostKt$NavHost$14$1.invoke(NavHost.kt:308)
     at androidx.navigation.compose.NavHostKt$NavHost$14$1.invoke(NavHost.kt:306)
     at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:109)
     at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:35)
     at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:401)
     at androidx.compose.runtime.saveable.SaveableStateHolderImpl.SaveableStateProvider(SaveableStateHolder.kt:85)
     at androidx.navigation.compose.NavBackStackEntryProviderKt.SaveableStateProvider(NavBackStackEntryProvider.kt:65)
     at androidx.navigation.compose.NavBackStackEntryProviderKt.access$SaveableStateProvider(NavBackStackEntryProvider.kt:1)
     at androidx.navigation.compose.NavBackStackEntryProviderKt$LocalOwnersProvider$1.invoke(NavBackStackEntryProvider.kt:52)
     at androidx.navigation.compose.NavBackStackEntryProviderKt$LocalOwnersProvider$1.invoke(NavBackStackEntryProvider.kt:51)
     at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:109)
     at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:35)
     at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:380)
     at androidx.navigation.compose.NavBackStackEntryProviderKt.LocalOwnersProvider(NavBackStackEntryProvider.kt:47)
     at androidx.navigation.compose.NavHostKt$NavHost$14.invoke(NavHost.kt:306)
     at androidx.navigation.compose.NavHostKt$NavHost$14.invoke(NavHost.kt:295)
     at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:139)
     at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:35)
     at androidx.compose.animation.AnimatedContentKt$AnimatedContent$6$1$5.invoke(AnimatedContent.kt:803)
     at androidx.compose.animation.AnimatedContentKt$AnimatedContent$6$1$5.invoke(AnimatedContent.kt:792)
     at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:118)
     at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:35)

The problem occurs when trying to load the ViewModel in this part, since the breakpoints reach there fine:
@Composable
internal fun ForYouRoute(
    onTopicClick: (String) -> Unit,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    viewModel: ForYouViewModel = hiltViewModel(),
) {
    val onboardingUiState by viewModel.onboardingUiState.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()
    val feedState by viewModel.feedState.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()
    val isSyncing by viewModel.isSyncing.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()
    val deepLinkedUserNewsResource by viewModel.deepLinkedNewsResource.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()

    //
}

I have tried several solutions, such as adding certain dependencies as suggested in this Github thread or this question, but the problem persists.
In the app/build.gradle file these are the dependencies I have that could be related to this error:
// Hilt
implementation 'androidx.hilt:hilt-common:1.2.0'
implementation "androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-compose:1.2.0"
implementation "androidx.hilt:hilt-work:1.2.0"

// Navigation
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-common-ktx:2.7.7"
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.7.7"
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-dynamic-features-fragment:2.7.7"
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.7.7"
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.7.7"
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-runtime-ktx:2.7.7"

// ViewModel
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-compose:2.8.0"
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.8.0'
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-savedstate:2.8.0"

It should be said that my current application is not multi-modular, as is the application mentioned above, in case this had to do with the error.
Any ideas on how to resolve this error?

The relevant part is missing: We need to see how your view model is constructed, including its dependencies. Actually, before posting it here try to narrow it down which of the view model's dependencies actually causes the error and post only a [mre].
